# Missing file properties in windows-explorer

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8, windows-explorer, external-hard-drive

I have a 3 laptops (two WIN10 and one WIN8) and 1 external hard drive.
All of them have the license activated.
The problem is only on the laptop with WIN8:
when I plug in the external hard drive, I'm not able to see in the explorer the properties of the file (Type, Size, Date modified...), but only the name.
Does anybody know where the problem can be?

Comment: Please post a screen shot.

Comment: Don't really understand what the 2 other laptops have to do with the question....

Comment: What does "the file" mean?

Answer (score 0):

On your laptop you probably have activated the **List** view . This view only shows the file name. Change the default Explorer view to **Details** and your problem should be gone.

Screenshots taken in Windows 10 but you should get the idea:

[image]

[image]